# "will be resolved by X" vs. "it is to be resolved by X"

Tags: comparison

I couldn't tell specifically what's the meaning of the following, especially "is to be resolved":

Politician: An issue is to be resolved by registering a consensus among our voters.

Does it mean that by registering the consensus, then an issue will probably (or definitely) be resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence lacks context. I could presume a particular context to make sense of it.  I could suppose that the politician would like to see how the voters collectively feel about an issue, and that will provide the necessary political motivation to act in accordance with that "will of the people".

So for example, maybe voters will vote a certain way, someone will be elected, and that elected person might be for or against an issue.  The voters consensus will (probably, most likely) resolve the issue one way or another.

Or it may be that the politician doesn't want to commit to any decision theirself, possibly because it's a close call and he/she doesn't want to offend half the population.  So the politician simply says that issue will be up to the will of the people.  Registration of the issue might be via vote or polling.